# Как правильно обработать русский URL в функции urlopen в Python?

Tags: python, url, utf-8, парсер

Просмотрел вопросы по данной тематике, но до сих пор не понятно, как обработать URL,содержащий кириллицу. Мне надо пропарсить статьи на русскоязычной и англоязычной Википедии, с англоязычной все хорошо, но когда я пытаюсь получить сайт русской Вики, появляются ошибки кодирования. Пробовал кодировать через .encode(), .decode(), однако не преуспел в этом. К примеру, я передаю сайт "[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Заглавная_страница](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)" Как правильно модифицировать данный код?

```
def read_site_content(self):#Данный метод открывает заданную страницу и выдает ее содержимое 
    return str(urlopen(self.site_name).read()))
```

Я использую класс, который наследуется от HTMLParser и перегружаю некоторые его методы.

Comment: У меня вечно проблемы с  urlopen, поэтому рекомендую использовать модуль requests. 
    >>> `import requests; url='https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Пьянство';  r = requests.get(url)`

в `r.text` будет код страницы.

но по-правильному, нужно `path` пропускать через `urllib.escape()`.

Comment: Связанные вопросы: чтобы url создать: [How to deal with unicode string in URL in python3?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11818515/4279), чтобы кодировку html-страницы найти: [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279), пример использования Wikipedia API: [UnicodeEncodeError in urllib2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32814347/4279)

Answer (score 1):

вот тебе пример как я парсил с русскими кейвордами (city, service)

```
import urllib.request import urllib.parse import json

url = 'https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text={0},{1}&type=biz&results=200&lang=ru_RU&apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'.format(urllib.parse.quote_plus(service),urllib.parse.quote_plus(city))
        print (url)
```

голос за
-1
голос против

если хочешь подробно то в Книге Python3 Прхоренок Н.А на 410 стр расписанно это http://www.bhv.ru/books/book.php?id=193418

если найдёшь в инте книгу то прочитаешь
http://scanlibs.com/python-3-samoe-neobhodimoe/

```
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        print(response)

string = response.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: @xmaster38, Я делал следующим образом:
`uurl = urlparse(self.site_name)`; 
`self.site_name = uurl.scheme + '://' + uurl.netloc + quote(uurl.path) + uurl.params + quote(uurl.query) + uurl.fragment`, но таким образом он мог обработать ТОЛЬКО ссылки с русскими буквами, а символы ":", "&" и тд он обрабатывал неправильно